# Is there any way to remove authentication key in pagadmin-4 URL?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I want to pagadmin 4 to run without key authendication in url.

Example url is : http://127.0.0.1:5051/?key=db7fe1d5-500a-48af-a85e-7895d848f67b

But whenever i run pgadmin-4 the new key will get generated.
Is there any way to disable this feature ?

My expected url is like : http://127.0.0.1:5051

Answer (score -1):

No it is implemented as security feature, if your pgAdmin4 is running without key then anyone can access it over LAN using the port, the key make sure your session is safe.

Comment: I like to disable this feature. Because everytime i need to share the url to my co-workers. I think for local development server this is unnecessary ?

Comment: If multiple people are using pgAdmin4 then I should suggest you to install it in Server mode https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.14/server_deployment.html, that way pgadmin4 will not require the key.